# Move a column in Report Builder 2.0

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder, report-builder2.0

How can I simply move a table column left or right in Report Builder using the UI (or text editor if necessary)?

I've tried to drag and drop, looked at menus, etc, and I can't find that option.  Is it in there?  So far I've had to delete and recreate a column every time I wanted to change its position.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can cut and paste - click the column you want to move and cut with Control-X. Then select a different column and paste with Control-V. That will place the old column to the left of the selected column.

Comment: Did not get it to work, I tried this: http://www.bidn.com/forums/microsoft-business-intelligence/reporting-services/367/moving-report-columns

Comment: After your comment, I realized that you are asking about Report Builder. My response was based on Business Intelligence Studio. Unfortunately I have no idea in Report Builder.

Comment: Dave, please remove this as the answer if it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

In **Report Builder 3.0** you can move columns like this:

1. Insert a new empty column
2. Copy (or cut) the text of the header and the text of the value in the new empty cells
3. Delete the old column

Or the easiest way is just to not move the columns but change their content by hovering over the column you want to change and select a new data type. After this you still need to update the column name and you're done.

I tried this too, but it only moves the values in the DataSet, not in the report:

1. Right click `DataSet1` in the left menu and select `Dataset Properties`
2. Select `Fields` on the left and click on any field to move it with the `blue arrows` on top

Comment: Thank you - not impressed with Report Builder...